# passing structure when calling C++ DLL function in C#

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, dll, struct

I need to use C# to control a test module with a C++ DLL, and below are the structures and init function originally defined in C++ header file

```
typedef unsigned char       uint8_t;
typedef unsigned long       uint32_t;
typedef unsigned short      uint16_t;
typedef unsigned char       bool_t;
typedef signed short        int16_t;
typedef signed char         int8_t;
typedef signed long         int32_t;

#define ER      0x2
#define BS      0x4000

typedef enum {
    nI2C,
    nSPI,
    nUSB,
    nSDIO
} mBus;

typedef uint8_t cAddr; 

typedef enum {
    nCPHA0=0,
    nCPHA1
} mPhase;

typedef enum {
    nCPOL0=0,
    nCPOL1
} mSpiPol;

typedef struct {
    mPhase cPha;
    mSpiPol cPol;
} mSpiCfg;

typedef struct {
    uint8_t             xo; 
    bool_t              init_bus_only;                          
    uint32_t            zone; 
    mBus             bustype;  
    mBus             transporttype; 
    cAddr         i2cAddr;
    mSpiCfg          spiCfg;
    bool_t              use_pmu; 
} mInitCfg;

typedef enum {
    OK = 0,
    FAIL = -1,  
    BUS_ALREADY_LOADED = -2,
    BUS_TYPE_UNKNOWN = -3,
    BUS_LOAD_LIBRARY_FAIL = -4,
    BUS_GET_PROC_FAIL = -5,
    BUS_INIT_FAIL = -6,
    Err_CHIP_INIT = -7
} retCode;

typedef struct {
    mInitCfg cfg;
} mDrvIn;

__declspec(dllexport) retCode cp_init(mDrvIn * inp);
```

In C++, it's called like below

```
static void init(void)
{
mDrvIn di;
retCode rc;

memset(&di, 0, sizeof(mDrvIn));

di.cfg.bustype = nI2C; 
di.cfg.init_bus_only = 1;
di.cfg.transporttype = di.cfg.bustype;
di.cfg.zone = ER | BS;

    rc = cp_init(&di);
    if(rc < 0) {
    printf("Failed to initialize. Error code %d: %s", rc, to_string(rc));
    return;
}
}
```

and I use below C# structures when calling the DLL function

```
using cAddr = System.Byte;
public enum mBus
{
    nI2C,
    nSPI,
    nUSB,
    nSDIO
};

public enum mPhase
{
    nCPHA0 = 0,
    nCPHA1
};

public enum mSpiPol
{
    nCPOL0 = 0,
    nCPOL1
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct mSpiCfg
{
    public mPhase cPha;
    public mSpiPol cPol;
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct mInitCfg
{
    public byte xo; 
    public byte init_bus_only; 
    public uint zone; 
    public mBus bustype; 
    public mBus transporttype; 
    public cAddr i2cAddr;
    public mSpiCfg spiCfg; 
    public byte use_pmu; 
};

public enum retCode
{
    OK = 0,
    FAIL = -1,  
    BUS_ALREADY_LOADED = -2,
    BUS_TYPE_UNKNOWN = -3,
    BUS_LOAD_LIBRARY_FAIL = -4,
    BUS_GET_PROC_FAIL = -5,
    BUS_INIT_FAIL = -6,
    Err_CHIP_INIT = -7
};

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct mDrvIn
{
    public mInitCfg cfg;
};

[DllImport("mdrv.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern retCode cp_init(ref mDrvIn inp);
```

I used below code to initialize

```
public static void init()
{
    mDrvIn di = new mDrvIn();
    retCode rc = new retCode();

    di.cfg.bustype = mBus.nI2C;
    di.cfg.init_bus_only = 1;
    di.cfg.transporttype = di.cfg.bustype;
    di.cfg.zone = 0x2 | 0x4000;

    rc = cp_init(ref di);
    if (rc < 0)
    {
        Console.Write("Failed to initialize. Error code: " + rc);
        return;
    }
}
```

The problem is that using C++ to initialize module works normally, but C# doesn't, it would always return error code -5(which means Bus error: failed to enumerate bus function inside DLL), the pointer of structure seems to be passed to DLL succefully without error, therefore I was wondering if there is something wrong with the structures I converted in C#, therefore the argument passed to C++ function is corrupted or something else, can anyone help me with this? thanks in advance.

Comment: Check `Marshal.SizeOf()` of your C# types and compare `sizeof()` of your C++ types.

Comment: printf("size => %d",di) this gives me 256   
Marshal.SizeOf(di) gives me 32   
but don't know what made this difference? my C# strucure is still wrong even after changing int to byte for bool_t?

Comment: There is no difference, `sizeof` returns bits and `Marshal.SizeOf` bytes, so they are the same.

Comment: Thanks, is there any other debug skill that I could use to find out what caused my C# structure to differ from C++?

Answer (score 0):

In your C++ code, you define `bool_t` as an `unsigned char` (8 bits), but in your C# code, you use an `int` (32 bits), so your structure stop being valid after `init_bus_only`.

Edit: Also, in your C++ code, you set `init_bus_only` to 1, and in your C# code you don't, but you should find that without help. Double check your code before asking.

Comment: Thanks, I changed them into byte as below

    public byte init_bus_only;
    public byte use_pmu;

but now I get BUS_LOAD_LIBRARY_FAIL instead, still can't figure out what else is wrong?

Comment: If nothing obvious is wrong, check what causes a `BUS_LOAD_LIBRARY_FAIL` in the documentation of the DLL.

Comment: Sorry I am aware of init_bus_only, actually I slightly changed the variable namings and forgot to change it back when posting, I set the initializing items and values exactly the same as C++ sample, still trying to find what caused the C# structure to fail.

Comment: In the document, it only says failed to load bus DLL, doesn't seem to be helpful.

Comment: NM, I was short of another DLL file, thanks guys for the help!